# AMFPHP AMF0 and AMF3

Tags: php, apache-flex, amf, amfphp

What are the difference between them?

Answer (score 5):

- **[AMF 0](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/1114283/amf0_spec_121207.pdf)**: Introduced in Flash Player 6 in 2001 and remained unchanged with the introduction of ActionScript 2.0 in Flash Player 7 and with the release of Flash Player 8.
- **[AMF 3](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/1114283/amf3_spec_05_05_08.pdf)**: In Flash Player 9, Action Script 3.0 was introduced. The new data types and language features made possible by these improvements prompted AMF to be updated.
- **[AMFPHP](http://www.amfphp.org/)**: Is a free open-source PHP implementation of the Action Message Format(AMF).

Answer (score 4):

Programs/Frameworks like AMFPHP/ZendAMF tend to fall back to AMF0 unless it uses a specific AMF3 feature. AMF 3 can pass a lot more things by reference, as well as supports sending a ByteArray and XML objects.

From the [Specification](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/1114283/amf3_spec_05_05_08.pdf):

- Object traits can now be sent by reference
- Strings can now be sent by reference
- int/uint type support
- flash.utils.ByteArray type support, can also be sent by reference
- flash.utils.IExternalizable support
- Variable length encoding scheme for integers to reduce data size
- References are sent using variable length integer
- String UTF-8 length uses variable length integer
- Array count uses variable length integer
- A single Array type marker covers both strict and ECMA Arrays
- Dates no longer send timezone information
- Dates can now be sent by reference
- XMLDocument UTF-8 length uses variable length integer
- XMLDocument can now be sent by reference
- XML type support, can also be sent by reference
- XML UTF-8 length uses variable length integer
- ByteArray type length uses variable length integer
- Boolean true and false are now sent as one byte type markers
- Unsupported type marker has been removed
- Reserved RecordSet and Movieclip type markers have been removed

Comment: A big and important difference to most of us is ByteArray for sure.